# Fill Mode для Background

Tags: android, qt

для Activity в манифесте задаётся тема через стиль
с единственной целью - отобразить через background картинку 
сплеша

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<manifest ...
    <application ....
        <activity ... android:theme="@style/splashScreenTheme">
```

стиль выглядит так:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<resources>
    <style name="splashScreenTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/logo</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/logo</item>
    </style>
```

работает, но немного плющит картинку - на разных устройствах по-разному

**Подскажите, есть способ управления способом заливки фона изображением?** Если аналоги смотреть у Qt, то там подходящие стили это PreserveAspectFit и PreserveAspectCrop.

Comment: я немного не понял: если вы используете activity как сплеш скрин, то почему вы не можете просто в разметке активити сделать ImageView, ему поставить src="нужная картинка" и там будет еще одно поле android:scaleType="". Там будут различные варианты, попробуйте и найдете тот, что нужен. Это поле как раз растягивает изображение и адаптирует подо все экраны.

Comment: К сожалению, опыта с андроидом мало. Проект на qt+qml+jni
В MainActivity onCreate создаю текст:
    LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
    ...
    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    textView.setText("this is TextView");
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    setContentView(linearLayout);

но он перекрывает или вообще не даёт загрузится main.qml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение в итоге было таким.

```js
public class MainActivity extends QtActivity {
  public ImageView m_splashScreen = null;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    m_splashScreen = new ImageView(this);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
    m_splashScreen.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); // ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
    m_splashScreen.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    this.addContentView(m_splashScreen, lp);
  }


  public class HideSplashScreenRunnable implements Runnable {
    private ImageView m_imageView;
    public HideSplashScreenRunnable(ImageView imageView) {
      m_imageView = imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
      m_imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
  }

  public void hideSplashScreen() {
    runOnUiThread(new HideSplashScreenRunnable(m_splashScreen));
  }
}
```

hideSplashScreen() вызывается для скрытия ImageView из main.cpp перед app.exec(). Это не самый лучший момент для закрытия заставки. Позднее думаем перенести закрытие в окончание загрузки qml страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Что то примерно такое -

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scale_type="center_crop"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:src="@drawable/background_race_light"/>
```

Ну а вообще я думаю проблема в android:scaleType="center", играй со значениями.

Comment: К сожалению, мне не понятно как этим воспользоваться. Попробовал вписать в <activity> манифеста - не помогло. Проект qt+qml+jni. Весь интерфейс на qml. В какой-то момент отображается main.qml, а до него необходимо держать заставку.